# pound on debian buster

Tags: pound, debian-buster

I had a debian jessie server, where I had pound managing https requests and forwarding them to varnish + apache. I upgraded the server to buster and everything was ok.

Now I'm migrating the server to a new one which is more powerful, and I'm installing the needed services, but I'm seeing that pound isn't in debian buster.

How can I solve this problem? can I install pound from debian sid repository? or perhaps from jessie repository?

What other solutions could I give a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you must use experimental version. Try this:

Add this line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non-free
```

into `/etc/apt/sources.list`

And as root (or use sudo) type:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t experimental install pound
```

Comment: With the experimental in the source list I am getting the error "unable to locate package pound"